# Laravel join queries AS

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel, eloquent

Any way of defining an `AS` for a query??

I have tried the following:

```
$data = News::order_by('news.id', 'desc')
    ->join('categories', 'news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->left_join('users', 'news.user_id', '=', 'users.id') // ['created_by']
    ->left_join('users', 'news.modified_by', '=', 'users.id') // ['modified_by']
    ->paginate(30, array('news.title', 'categories.name as categories', 'users.name as username'));
```

The problem is that `['name']` from categories will be replaces with the one from `users`. Any way of having them with different names?

Having the aliases above... how can I create an alias where both joins return `users.name` ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`paginate()` method's second parameter accepts **array** of table columns to select in the query. So this part:

```
paginate(30, array('news.title, category.name'));
```

must be like this:

```
paginate(30, array('news.title', 'category.name'));
```

**UPDATE** *(after you changed the question)*

Try this:

```
->paginate(30, array('news.title', 'categories.name as category_name', 'users.name as user_name'));
```

**UPDATE 2** *(after you changed the question, again)*

You can use alias on tables, too:

```
$data = News::order_by('news.id', 'desc')
    ->join('categories', 'news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->join('users as u1', 'news.user_id', '=', 'u1.id') // ['created_by']
    ->join('users as u2', 'news.modified_by', '=', 'u2.id') // ['modified_by']
    ->paginate(30, array('news.title', 'categories.name as categories', 'u1.name as creater_username', 'u2.name as modifier_username'));
```

Answer (score 4):

More simple and plain answer to this question is and what I was looking for that Eloquent supports aliases directly with table names or columns, for example:

```
$users = DB::table('really_long_table_name AS t')
           ->select('t.id AS uid')
           ->get();
```